# when this code executes, it shows no output. Why is that?

Tags: c++, c, loops, for-loop

Following code has no output when it executes. Can anyone explain the following code?

```cpp
int main() {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2)
      printf("%d\t", i);
    else
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `else break;` - how many iterations do you expect to get with that line in your loop?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, please read the description of tags that you apply.

Comment: Great time to learn how to step through each line of code in a debugger.

Comment: First time through the loop `i` is zero. `0 % 2` yields *false*, so the `else` part executes ==> the loop is exited and the program terminates.

Comment: I've seen a few examples recently where `break` seems to be being used as a kind of null statement, without the coder understanding what it really does.

Comment: by very logic of  human language, one should have thought to use `continue`. That's the idea of K&R behind those two keywords. But actually whole "else" thing isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

`0 % 2` gives `false` so the loop terminates at the first iteration without calling the `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two issues:

#### 1.

`if (i % 2)`

The condition of `(i % 2)` evaluates to `false` because the calculation - `0` divided by `2` - result in `0`  -> `0 / 2 = 0`. The remainder is also `0`.

#### 2.

`else break;`

That provides the result if `(i % 2)` is not `true` (which is the case with `0` at the first iteration) you immediately will break out of the `for` loop. Omit the `break;` statement in general, if you want to proof if all values from `0` to `9` have an remainder when divided by `2` or not.

Note that to pack `break;` in an separate `else` statement is nonetheless redundant.

---

Side note:

`j` has no use in your code.

---

I guess what you want is something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   int i, j;

   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
     if ( ( j = i % 2 ) )
       printf("(%d / 2) has a remainder of %d.\n", i, j);
     else
       printf("(%d / 2) has no remainder.\n", i);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
(0 / 2) has no remainder.
(1 / 2) has a remainder of 1.
(2 / 2) has no remainder.
(3 / 2) has a remainder of 1.
(4 / 2) has no remainder.
(5 / 2) has a remainder of 1.
(6 / 2) has no remainder.
(7 / 2) has a remainder of 1.
(8 / 2) has no remainder.
(9 / 2) has a remainder of 1.
```

[Try this code online](https://godbolt.org/z/JMbkZq).

Note that by the division `1 / 2`, the result `0.5` is raised to the nearest upper integral value `1` because of the implicit `double` to `int` conversion.

Answer (score -1):

`i % 2` gives the remainder of the Euclidian division of `i` by 2. It does NOT mean "i is divisible by 2". If the latter is true, then `i % 2` gives 0 which implicitely converts to `false`. If it is false, then `i % 2` gives 1 which implicitely converts to `true`. Therefore, in the first iteration, the conditional ex^pression evaluates to false so you break out of the loop immediately.

If you want to check the divisibility of `i` by 2, you must use `i % 2 == 0`.

Comment: The question does not say anything about what the purpose of `i % 2` is. It asks why nothing is printed. You answer explains what `%` mod does, but not why nothing is printed.

Comment: @t.niese Right, thanks for the info !